# How to find the weighted edit distance between two strings with Agrepl

Tags: r, string, approximate

I am having difficult time understanding how the edit distance is calculated in the agrepl function. I am trying to output the distance that agrepl calculates between two strings. I used the "adist" and "stringdist" function but it gives the total # of insertions/deletions etc, not the weighted distance that goes into the agrepl function.